# Removing an unbind on a button in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function getData(url) {
    $.getJSON(url, function(result) {
        $('#formNav ul').append('<ul/>')
        $.each(result, function() {
            var list = $('#formNav li'),
            listItem = $('<li/>'),
            html = listItem.append($('<h5/>').text(this.name));
            $.each(this.items, function() {
                listItem.append($('<a />').attr('href', this.id).text(this.name))
            });
            list.append(html)
        });
    });
};




$(function(){


        var Menu = {

                $menu: $('.config-nav #formNav'),
                $trades : $(".config-nav select#tradesmanList"),
                $skills : $(".config-nav select#jobList"),

                init: function(){
                        var $menu = Menu.$menu;

                        // Set menu up
                        $menu.children("li").addClass('closed');
                        $menu.find(".js-reveal").hide();

                        Menu.$skills.attr("disabled", "disabled");
                        Menu.$trades.on("change", function($skills){
                        Menu.$skills.removeAttr("disabled");
                        });

                        // bind to click on the item...
                        $menu.on("click", "h4", this.toggle);


                },

                toggle: function() {
                        //  Toggle the hide show of the drill down menu
                        var $this = $(this),
                                $category = $this.parent();
                    console.log($this.parent().index());

                    var data = getData("test.json");

                    $category.addClass("loading").toggleClass("open");
                    $this.next(".reveal").delay(100).toggle(0, function(){
                        $category.Data;
                        $category.removeClass("loading");


                    });
                }

        };

       Menu.init();
});
```

I have a function that returns json data , i then call this function in the  Menu function to display the data however every time i click the button the data just keeps being generated instead i want it to display the data and then once it is clicked again hide the data? if anyone has any advice that would be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When ever you call the toggle function You seem to get the data using

```
var data = getData("test.json"); and then use it to populate the list..
```

Why don't you move the getData method to outside the toggle function and instead move it to to init function .. Look's like it should be fine then..

Comment: I have moved it to before the line  // bind to click on the item...
                        $menu.on("click", "h4", this.toggle); but it still seems to be repeating the data? Do i still call category.data in the toggle function? Thanks